# Calling startTimer Method Multiple Times(Java)

Tags: java, timer, actionlistener

So I've been browsing the web for answers but feel overwhelmed and can't seem to find an explanation of this.  For one of my classes we were given an example with code very similar to what I'm using and I copied it (dangerous I know but not sure how else to go about it.)

I'm trying to make it so that when a button is pressed a JLabel reads a certain text and 5 seconds later that text disappears. I have been able to do this successfully, but there is a catch.  I have 6 JButtons that share the same ActionListener which can, under the right conditions, call the startStatusTimer method.

If one button is pressed, and within 5 seconds another button is pressed, it starts another timer, and the more buttons I press the more timers I get that never seem to never stop.  The text eventually goes away, but only after the 5 seconds has passed from the the first button is pressed.

I keep getting count values >5 printing out after pressing buttons multiple times within a few seconds but I do not see how this can be because of the if statement.

It does not seem like good coding practice to leave a bunch of timers running in the background so how do I stop them?

```
private void startStatusTimer()
{
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
    {
        int count=0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
            if(count>=5)
            {
                statusLabel.setText("");
                statusTimer.stop();
            }
        }
    };
    statusTimer = new Timer(second, taskPerformer);
    statusTimer.start();
}
```

The System.out.println is simply for debugging.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create `statusTimer` only if it's `null` and clear it to `null` upon finish of your logic. Probably, it's worth to make this code thread-safe as well, by adding `synchronized (someFinalObject)` to listener and to `startStatusTimer` last two statements.

Comment: Thank you Victor Sorokin, I added the null statements and it did stop multiple timers from going off... the only thing is I want the last Timer that was attempted to start to be the beginning of the 5 second timer.

If button is pressed and 2 seconds passes and the button is pressed again, I want there to be 5 seconds left until the JLabel clears, not 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It does not seem like good coding practice to leave a bunch of timers running in the background

Generally, no, you don't want to have multiple Swing `Timer`s running if you can help it.  They won't scale well (the more you add, the worst things become).  Where you trying to do the same or similar things, try and use as few `Timer`s as possible.

Instead, try creating a single instance of the `Timer`...

```
 public class ... {
     private Timer wipeOutTimer;

     public ...() {
          wipeOutTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
              {
                  statusLabel.setText("");
              }
          });
          wipeOutTimer.setRepeats(false);
    }
```

Then in your `startStatusTimer` you can check the state of the `Timer`...

```
private void startStatusTimer() {
    if (!wipeOutTimer.isRunning()) {
        wipeOutTimer.start();
    }
```

This will ensure that no matter how many times you press buttons, while there will only ever be a single `Timer` running and it will only be started once within a 5 second period.

> so how do I stop them?

This depends on what you are trying to do.  You could use `setRepeats(false)` so timer will only run once.  You could also use `isRunning` to check to see if the `Timer` is already running and even use `restart` to cause the timer to reset should you want to...

> How can I make the timer restart to 5 seconds everytime the button is pressed?

Simply call `restart`

```
private void startStatusTimer() {
    if (!wipeOutTimer.isRunning()) {
        wipeOutTimer.start();
    } else {
        wipeOutTimer.restart();
    }
```

You can actually just call `restart` every time, but this illustrates some additional functionality you may no know about...

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I see the way you did it is more clean and concise and it does keep the timers from starting.  One thing though... as I see it the timer does not restart to 5 seconds everytime the button is pressed, but keeps counting down the initial 5 seconds from the first press.  How can I make the timer restart to 5 seconds everytime the button is pressed?

I could try maybe:

private void startStatusTimer() {
    if (wipeOutTimer.isRunning()) {
        wipeOutTimer.stop();
        wipeOutTimer.start();
    }

I will give this a shot...

Comment: The `Timer` is setup not to repeat, so once it reaches the first 5 seconds, it will stop.  If, you want to "reset" the `Timer` each time `startStatusTimer` is called, then when `isRunning` is true, simply call `restart`, which will reset the timer...

Comment: One last question.  With how I did it originally it continued to repeat the actionperformed method every second simply because it is the default to repeat?  setsRepeat(false) changed it to only repeat one time then?  Sorry I'm sure this seems super basic for most but I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: Yes, `setRepeats` defines if you want the `Timer` to continue clicking (like a clock) or stop after it's first run (like a stop watch)